# command to get current volume level

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb

Is there any adb command to know the current volume level of android device?

I find this somewhere:
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "select * from system where name like '%volume%';"

but it's throwing following error:
Error: unable to open database "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db": unable to open database file

Comment: Is your device rooted? You have to be rooted to access the `/data` partition directly..

Comment: Yes, my device is rooted. I am able to do other tasks for which device is required to be rooted.

Comment: Ensure manually using a file explorer if there's a file named `settings.db` under `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/` directory..

Comment: No. it's not there. Neither I could find it using find command. Is there some other way to get volume level?

Comment: settings.db is removed since Marshmallow I guess. And also, this command seemed to work till JellyBean or something: `settings get system volume_music`. It returns some other irrelevant value now..

Answer (score 2):

Use command **adb shell dumpsys audio**. It will list all the volume related information. e.g for alarm volume look for **STREAM_ALARM** in output logs.

```
- STREAM_ALARM:
    Muted: false
    Min: 0
    Max: 7
    Current: 2 (speaker): 7, 40000000 (default): 6
    Devices: speaker
```